Need and Expert advice
I'm trying to make a library in SharePoint.
The documents are only for viewing and not to modify.
The documents to be shown need to be filtered by department.
So far I have found two ways to do that, one is through a web part that is called docs listing and the other one is through the library web part itself.
The truth is that I don't understand the pros and cons of each
I provide an image below for you to identify the 2 options I'm talking about.

I need a clear picture of which object serves my purpose the most.
I greatly will appreciate your comments!

"Docs Listing" is not a SharePoint default web part. It might be a custom web part developed by your company or third party web part.
